# Android - how to launch the device "file system" programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, file-manager

I am building an app that needs to launch the android in-built file system app at the click of a button. I am not sure what to call it, it says "Documents" as its title and lists out all files present on the device. This is what it looks like -[image]

Comment: This is correct app. What is problem?

Comment: The question is, how do I launch this from my own app. The screenshot is of when I launch it using Evernote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The image you have added is of Documents application. 
Android 4.4 (API level 19) introduces the **Storage Access Framework (SAF)**. The SAF makes it simple for users to browse and open documents, images, and other files across all of their their preferred document storage providers.*

---

You can lunch this application via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`

```
// ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is the intent to choose a file via the system's file
// browser.
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

// Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as a
// file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

// Filter to show only images, using the image MIME data type.
// If one wanted to search for ogg vorbis files, the type would be "audio/ogg".
// To search for all documents available via installed storage providers,
// it would be "*/*".
intent.setType("image/*");

startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
```

---

***Read more about [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).***